# SSIS Control Flow - set a precedent constraint on entire group of Data Flow tasks

Tags: ssis

I have about 20 data flow tasks arranged into a group in my control flow window. I'm fine with them executing in parallel; in fact I prefer it.

But I need to add an Execute SQL Task and I need it to run completely before any of my data flow tasks begin.  It doesn't look like I can connect a precedence constraint from the Execute SQL Task to the group of data flow tasks (I was really hoping it would be that easy.)

Is my only option to create a precedence constraint from my Execute SQL Task to EACH of the data flow tasks?  Seems like there should be a simpler solution.

(SQLServer 2005)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of a Sequence Container.  Add a Sequence container to your task flow.  Then move (drag and drop will do it) all of your data flow tasks into the container.  Now you can create a single precedence constraint from your Execute SQL Task to the Sequence container.  Everything in the Sequence Container will not execute until the rules of the Precedence Constraint are met.